# Photos on Mac is sending to iCloud but still showing 3gb of photos on my local

Tags: icloud, photos

I am still seeing that Photos is taking up space on my local but all new photos are being offloaded to iCloud. How do I find the photos that are NOT in iCloud and are staying on my local system?

[image]

Comment: Photos doesn‘t *offload*, it syncs the library into iCloud and will at least keep a lowres version locally. Have you set „optimize storage“ in Photos settings?

Answer (score 0):

Photos does not remove local copies unless you are low on storage **and** have Optimize Mac Storage enabled in Photos > Settings > iCloud.

Expect it to always take local storage for thumbnails, regardless of overall disk space.